# Search through text for specific words. Efficiency issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a method to go through a word document and look for certain keywords. These keywords are added into an ArrayList. If a keyword is found it is added to another ArrayList. As far as I'm aware my code goes through every item in the keywords array and checks the document if it's there. Is there a way to make my code more efficient and maybe compare all keywords to the first word, then to the second and so on? It's pretty slow with larger files (it's obvious) but it shouldn't be that slow I guess.

This is my method

```
public final void findKeywordsInDocument(POITextExtractor te, Map<String,ArrayList<Keyword>> tagMap, ArrayList<Integer> existingTags, ArrayList<Integer> KeywordsFound) {

    final String[] tagArrays = {"KEYWORDS", "CUSTOMERS", "SYSTEM_DEPS", "MODULES", "DRIVE_DEFS", "PROCESS_IDS"};

    for(int i=0; i<tagArrays.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nNew " + tagArrays[i] + " found in the document:");
        ArrayList<Keyword> al = tagMap.get(tagArrays[i]);

        int itemsFound = 0;

        for (Keyword item : al) {
            if (te.getText().contains(item.getName())) {    
                /*
                 * Check if a document is not tagged with this keyword already
                 */
                if (!existingTags.contains(item.getId())) {
                    KeywordsFound.add(item.getId());
                    System.out.println(item.getName());
                    itemsFound++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(itemsFound == 0) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I call it

```
  Map<String,ArrayList<Keyword>> tagMap = new HashMap<>();
  tagMap.put("KEYWORDS", Keywords);
  tagMap.put("CUSTOMERS", Customers);
  tagMap.put("SYSTEM_DEPS", SystemDeps);
  tagMap.put("MODULES", Modules);
  tagMap.put("DRIVE_DEFS", DriveDefs);
  tagMap.put("PROCESS_IDS", ProcessIDs);
ArrayList<Integer> KeywordsFound;
if(file_name.endsWith(".docx") || file_name.endsWith(".docm")) {
    ArrayList<Integer> existingTags = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(resultSet.getBinaryStream(3)); //blob
    XWPFWordExtractor wordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);

    KeywordsFound = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    findKeywordsInDocument(wordExtractor, tagMap, existingTags, KeywordsFound);
}
```

Keyword class

```
public class Keyword {

   private int id;
   private String name;

  public Keyword() {
    int id;
    String name;
  }

  public Keyword(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  } 

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: don't loop an array of strings, simply add them to a hashtable or some similar structure and then for each word in the document just check if your map contains the current word you are at, if it does then you know it's a keyword.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you're doing a case-sensitive comparison. Following on from @RAZ_Muh_Taz's suggestion, you may wish to call `toLowerCase()` on each term as you add it to the collection.

Comment: I have few categories of my ArrayLists like customers, modules, system dependencies. Do you mean that I shall put them into separate hashtables like hashtable customers, hashtable modules or would it be better to just keep them in one big hashtable? It's first time I come across hashtables.

Comment: You're better off with something like `HashSet` unless you can think of something meaningful to attach to each one as a value. You can keep your `ArrayList`s and then just compare each one against the set.

Comment: So what exactly should have been in the hashset if you look at my code? What data shall I compare against what?